# Eventlog, impersonation and Access Denied Win32Exception

Tags: c#, impersonation, event-log, win32exception

I am using a dedicated account (with SDDL policy) to write event log entries to a custom event log. For this I use WindowsImpersonationContext and obtain a token with LogonUser:

```
WindowsIdentity impersonationIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(ptr);            
WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = impersonationIdentity.Impersonate();
EventLog.WriteEntry("MyCustomSource", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), EventLogEntryType.Warning);
impersonationContext.Undo();
NativeMethods.CloseHandle(ptr);
```

This piece of code produces event log entries, yet I also get a Win32Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source 'MyCustomSource'. You may not have write access. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
```

Now, the exception disappears if I place a Thread.Sleep(500) after the impersonation line:

```
WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = impersonationIdentity.Impersonate();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```

What is causing this exception and how come the event log entries get written even with the access denied exception?

Edit:
And ofc I've registered the event source with the associated log before using it. I only included small code snippets to keep the message short.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old and seems not answered.
It looks like my problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997152/registereventsource-fails-with-access-denied-for-impersonated-user-in-asp-net).

I link this question to my question since I think its the same problem and I investigated it a bit further. It has to do with the logonType that is specified in the LogonUser() call.

Maybe it helps.